# Mantle and Core Data - Could not serialize managed object

Tags: ios, core-data, github-mantle

I am trying to store a JSON into Coredata using Mantle and I have the following code:

```
        PPCoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [PPCoreDataStack defaultStack]; //my custom wrapper for CoreData a simple accessor really

        NSManagedObject *mob = [MTLManagedObjectAdapter managedObjectFromModel:userModel insertingIntoContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext error:&error];

        if(mob) {
            NSLog(@"Mob: %@", mob);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Mob Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        [coreDataStack saveContext];
```

I am getting the following error:

```
        Mob Error: Could not serialize managed object
```

I am not sure why. I am new to core data so please help me understand what could be going wrong here.

Comment: That's not a Core Data error, that's a Mantle error.

Comment: Thanks for the info Tom. Would you be able to tell me why is Mantle giving that error?

Comment: No, I've never used Mantle, but I thought it might help narrow things down. Maybe the discussion here will help: https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/issues/252

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was just stupid. The entity was not in the model.